Help updating 34 year old document to run with modern LaTeX
I used to be proficient with LaTex.  Thirty years ago.  I'm afraid I don't understand some of the modern standards.  And I have a document I created 34 years ago that uses the documentstyle command, and ran fine. I still have the PDF it produced.  But when I try to produce it now, LaTeX goes into "LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE", and then fails with the vague message "! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."
I tried changing the documentstyle to a documentclass command, but again got lost in issues I no longer have a command of.  Any chance someone can tell me what I need to do to update the document to run today, hopefully without compatibility mode?  The file can be found here:
[link was removed because it was not permanent.  As per @jasper habicht comment I will try to figure out how to provide with some other approach next time.  Full file with fixes can be found in the solution below.]
Thanks so much - Bill

Your unedited file compiles fine (although with a compatibility mode warning) by me (texlive 2024).

It is not a good idea to post links that may rot over time making the linked file inaccessible. Please try to provide a minimal working example instead.

Agreed @JasperHabicht.  I will try and figure out how to do this next time, thanks.

Very little to change really. I have put some notes at the end.
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
%      Wm. M. Stewart, 6 March 1990
%
%      'Party Financing and Proportional Representation'
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\title{Party Financing \\
 and \\
Proportional Representation: \\
A Submission to the Royal Commission on
Electoral Reform and Party Financing}

\author{Wm.\@ Mott Stewart \\
Fredericton, New Brunswick }

\date{3 March 1990}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Introduction}

\begin{quote}
\emph{The Democracy which shall make government the organ of
public reason\ldots is yet in the womb of the future.}
\ Goldwin Smith --- 1887
\end{quote}

The essence of the democratic ideal is simply stated---that
every citizen be accorded complete equality in the electoral
process.

Canada's present electoral system cannot be said to fully
satisfy this criteria, for it violates the spirit of the
democratic ideal in two important ways:
\begin{enumerate}
\item It is privately financed; and
\item It lacks proportional representation.
\end{enumerate}

After several years of thought, I have come to the
conclusion that two reforms are required more than any other
to make our electoral system truly democratic:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Public financing of our political parties; and
\item A proportional representation system.
\end{enumerate}

If a priority were to be assigned to these two reforms, I
believe the first to be of the paramount concern.

In section~\ref{prfn}, I detail a democratic, practical, and
inexpensive mechanism for the implementation of public
financing of our political parties, including figures.

In section~\ref{prrp}, I present a simple and workable
mechanism for implementation of a proportional
representation system.  I have written a software system to
model this mechanism, and include a copy with an example in
the appendices.

\clearpage

\section{Party Financing}
\label{prfn}

\begin{quote}
\emph{This evil is the bane of Democracy; it is the nightmare
of every man in public life who is anxious to give service
to the State.} \ Clifford Sifton, in \emph{New Era,} 1917,
regarding campaign  fund-raising.
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}
\emph{Gratefulness is always regarded as an important factor
in dealing with democratic governments.} \ John Aird, Jr.,
President of Beauharnois Corporation, H. of C., Debate,
1931, 4260.
\end{quote}

Our present electoral system violates the essence of the
democratic ideal, in that it allows private interests,
primarily corporations and unions, to finance our public
electoral process through financial contributions to
registered political parties.

In a privately financed democracy (surely a contradiction in
terms) the democratic playing field is neither level nor
equal. Less wealthy---but no less legitimate---interests do
not have parity with more wealthy interests.  This is the
antithesis of the spirit of equality that is the essence of
the democratic ideal.

There are four substantive objections to the practice
of privately financing political parties:
\begin{enumerate}
\item It makes a mockery of the cornerstone of Democracy,
      that every citizen should be accorded equality in the
      electoral process.  In practice, private interests may
      effectively have hundreds of votes, through their
      ability to finance the election campaigns of the
      various parties;
\item Shareholders of corporations and members of unions do
      not necessarily support the donations made on their
      behalf;
\item The demands of fund-raising detract from time and
      effort that parties could better devote to more
      constructive matters; and
\item There is an undeniable moral indebtedness, a
      gratefulness, that accompanies the financial support
      of private interests.
\end{enumerate}

In my view, this last objection is the fundamental and fatal
flaw of a privately financed Democracy.

To be supported by private interests carries with it an
implied requirement to be sympathetic to these interests.
This sympathy, so necessary to gaurentee continued support,
may be manifested in small ways or large ways, by a gentle
restriction of flexibilty on policy issues, or by major
compromises of the public interest. In any form, this
coercive effect is absolutely incompatible with the spirit
of the democratic ideal.

\subsection{An Impractical Solution}

One thing is clear, the solution to this dilemma is most
assuredly not a return to fund-raising exclusively from
individuals.

This option is first and obviously impractical: it is
clearly true that one cannot run a national campaign on the
proceeds from selling fudge.

More importantly, this option does not address the primary
inequity of a privately financed Democracy:  the distortion
of the principle that every citizen should be accorded
complete equality in the electoral process.

Any privately funded Democracy, whether funded by
organizations or by individuals, will have the fundamentally
undemocratic property that less wealthy interests will not
have parity with more wealthy interests. The electoral
process, like heaven and the battlefield, is the one arena
where material wealth should not be a significant factor.

\subsection{The Democratic Solution: Public Financing}

The natural solution for this dilemma is at once a bold
solution, a workable solution, and a cheap solution.  The
natural solution is a quintessentially democratic solution:
the public financing of our political parties.

Indeed, this solution is so simple and practical that it
takes but twenty seconds to describe. It is this simplicity,
perhaps most of all, that recommends it for serious and
sober contemplation:

\begin{enumerate}

\item Levy a democracy financing tax of \$$1.00$ per
      person per year; and
\item Distribute the funds raised by the democracy financing
      tax to the political parties strictly proportional to
      their popular vote in the last
      election.\footnote{Independent candidates are treated
      in much the same way, and are discussed at the end of
      the section.}
\end{enumerate}

At one dollar per person per year, this mechanism is cheap.
No-one can quibble with the cost.  Indeed, a dollar a year
is a trifling amount for the support of our most important
institution.

The method of distribution---proportional to popular
vote---is the simplest mechanism, and the fairest
mechanism---decided as it is by the people themselves.  It
is the democratic mechanism.

With regard to numbers, this mechanism will provide a party
with one third of the popular vote with about \$6,333,000 a
year, or \$25,300,000 over four years. On an individual
riding basis, this would amount to about \$90,000
each.\footnote{These figures are calculated on the basis of
19,000,000 Canadians of voting age.}

At this level of financing, the party could direct mail
their election platform to every household in the country
several times over.

The members of the commision will determine if these figures
are too low, or too high. In my view, one should err on the
side of too high, in order to ensure that all parties---both
those with forty percent of the popular vote and those with
twenty percent of the popular vote---have a fair opportunity
to effectively communicate their policies to the citizenry,
and thereby allow merit, not funding, to be the deciding
factor.  Above a certain level, such as that suggested here,
this principle of fairness is ensured.

The idea that a democracy worthy of the name should finance
its political parties from the public purse is not nearly as
large a leap of faith as it might at first seem.  Indeed,
political parties are largely funded from the public purse
right now, through the practice of allowing financial
contributions to political parties to be treated as tax
deductions.  The mechanism proposed here merely makes the
practice democratic.

\subsection{The Advantages of Public Financing}

The advantages of a publicly funded democracy, and of this
mechanism in particular, are interesting and
thought-provoking:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Democracy is restored: every citizen is accorded
      complete equality in the electoral process;
\item Parties will become solely responsible to their
      members for the use of their finances;
\item Parties will be able to free up time and effort from
      fund-raising to devote to more constructive matters; and
\item Interestingly, citizens will be provided with a
      powerful incentive to vote, knowing as they will that
      their ballot is in effect an allocation of their
      portion of the democracy financing tax to the party of
      their choice.  Moreover, if there is a fifty percent
      turnout at the polls, every citizen who \emph{does}
      vote will know that their ballot effectively allocates
      not only their portion of the democracy financing tax,
      but someone else's as well, providing added incentive.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{An Impassioned Plea}

Through the recommendations of this commission, Canada has
an opportunity to make an unprecedented and courageous step
towards a truly democratic electoral system---an opportunity
to move away from a privately financed democracy and thereby
dramatically improve the regard Canadians have for
politicians, political parties, and the political
process---an opportunity to make Canada a bold and visionary
example of contemporary democracy---an opportunity to make
Canada what might be fairly called the most democratic
country in the world.

I urge you to do so.

\vspace{1in}

\centerline{\textbf{Afterword: Independent Candidates}}

Independent candidates who ran in the last election and
intend to run in the next are treated by the same
rules: allocated funds strictly according to their
proportional vote.

Independent candidates who did \emph{not} run in the last
election, but do intend to run in the next, should be
allowed to register signatures of support with the Elections
Officer which will be considered as equivalent to votes for
funding purposes---from the date the signatures are
registered.  For example, a new Independent candidate who
has had five hundred signatures registered for one year will
receive \$500; a candidate who has had three thousand
signatures registered for four years will receive \$12,000;
and so on.

The (relatively small) amount of this type of funding should
be taken off the top of the entire amount raised annually by
the democracy  financing tax.

The same procedure may  be used by new
political parties.


\clearpage

\section{Proportional Representation}
\label{prrp}

\begin{quote}
\emph{Democracy may be simply defined as the people in action.}
\ Henry Wise Wood, Grain Grower's Guide, July 2, 1919, 7.
\end{quote}

Almost every democratic country in the world has created
their own implemenation of the democratic ideal. Canadians
have a hand-me-down system inherited from the British.
While this system is one of the world's best, it is not a
Canadian system---it does not spring from Canadian values
and experience.  It is time we considered some improving
alterations.

The well-known and glaring flaw of the British Parliamentary
System is its non-proportional character.

For example, in the most extreme case, party A could win
50\% plus one of the ridings each with 50\% plus one of the
votes, while party B receives all remaining votes in all
ridings.  Party A would then form the goverment with 25\% of
the popular vote, while party B would be relegated to the
opposition with 75\% of the popular vote!

Although the above extreme case is unlikely to occur in
practice, it is unquestionably possible with our present
electoral system.  Less extreme but no less unjust
distortions occur in every election.

The Canadian electoral process cannot call itself truly
democratic if it does not match the political complexion of
the House of Commons to the will of the people as expressed
by the popular vote.  A system which \emph{approximates}
the will of the people---sometimes favoring one party,
sometimes another---is a grave affront to our sense of
natural justice, and should be made more exact.

The solution to this dilemma is a proportional
representation system.

\subsection{A Mechanism for Proportional Representation}

There are two requirements that a proportional
representation system must accomodate:
\begin{enumerate}
\item All candidates which actually win their riding must be
      seated; and
\item The political complexion of the House of Commons must
      reflect the will of the people as expressed by the
      popular vote.
\end{enumerate}

I here propose one mechanism for implementation of a
proportional representation system that meets the important
demand of simplicity, and also accomodates the above
requirements.
\begin{enumerate}
\item All candidates which actually win their ridings are
      seated;
\item No further candidates from the most over-represented
      party are seated; and
\item Second-place candidates from the under-represented
      parties are seated as necessary, \emph{starting with
      the most closely contested ridings,} until the
      political complexion of Parliament matches the popular
      vote.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Ramifications of the Mechanism}

I have implemented a software model of this mechanism and
observed its performance. The advantages and ramifications
of the mechanism are as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\label{lbla}
      Losing candidates from under-represented parties as
      well as winning candidates will be seated in the most
      closely contested ridings;
\item On average, the size of the House will increase by
      approximately twenty percent;
\item
\label{lblb}
      There may be more minority governments;
\item The citizenry will be provided with a powerful
      incentive to vote, even for a candidate they consider
      likely to lose, in order to support the party of their
      choice as a whole; and
\item Native Canadians can attain proportional representation
      in the House in a natural manner.
\end{enumerate}

With regard to point~\ref{lbla}, this may appear unjust to
the winning candidate. Two responses are possible:  (a) the
larger principle of proportional representation takes
precedence; (b) the seated losing candidate \emph{has} been
supported by a large number of the voters, since we begin
seating with the most closely contested ridings.  If these
responses are insufficient, one may wish to strike a
compromise, by ranking the winning candidate as `senior' and
the second-place candidate as `junior', with appropriate
demarcation of priveleges. Another idea would be to specify
that no second-place candidate may be seated who has lost by
more than seven percent (say).  Alternatively, an intriguing
idea would be to send these second-place candidates to another
place---perhaps the Senate.

With regard to point~\ref{lblb}, such a development would be
simply a reflection of the will of the people, and a
beneficial development.  Minority governments are among the
most effective, progressive, and constructive of
governments; Mr. Pearson's, Mr. Trudeau's, and Mr.
Peterson's minority governments are excellent, convincing
examples.

\subsection{A Software Model}

To demonstrate this mechanism, I have written a software
system to model it.  A copy of this software (written in the
Fortran language) may be found in appendix~\ref{appb}.

An example of the system in operation may be found in
appendix~\ref{appa}.  This example consists of 100 ridings,
in each of which three candidates are running, one each from
the Left-Wing, Centre, and Right-Wing parties.

I recommend this system for your examination and use.  You
may wish to run it on real data, for example on the actual
data for each of the last ten Federal Elections.  It would
be interesting to see the results.  If called upon, I would
be pleased to assist the commission in this regard.



\clearpage

\appendix
\section{A Proportional Representation Example}
\label{appa}

The following example consists of 100 ridings, in each of
which there are three parties running---the Left-Wing party,
the Centre party, and the Right-Wing party.

The system runs in four phases:
\begin{enumerate}
\item The outright winners in each riding are determined;
\item The difference between the proportional vote and the
      number of candidates elected are calculated for each
      party. The number of additional members required from
      each under-represented party is calculated and a
      table of statistics is printed;
\item The appropriate number of members from each
      under-represented party are added, starting with the
      most closely contested ridings; and
\item An updated table of statistics is printed.
\end{enumerate}



\clearpage

\section{The Proportional Representation Software}
\label{appb}

The following is a copy of the software system used to
implement the proportional representation system which ran
the example in appendix~\ref{appa}.

It is about four hundred lines long, written in the Fortran
computer language.

\end{document}

What changed?
I ran a diff on the before and after files, which I will summarize here.

The first change is to use a class instead of an old style.
 < \documentstyle [11pt,titlepage]{article}                                        
 ---
 > \documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}


Then move \begin{document} down a bit so that it is after \title, \date, and \author. (This is optional, see comments).

Next, get rid of the unhelpful "short hands"
< \newcommand{\be}{\begin{enumerate}}                                             
< \newcommand{\bln}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}                                        
< \newcommand{\ee}{\end{enumerate}}                                               

These are not really necessary;  in modern LaTeX it is generally
better to use the built-in environments as is.  Many modern editors provide syntax-assistance to help.

Modernize {\em ...} inside braces, and use \emph{...} instead
< Independent candidates who did {\em not\/} run in the last                      
---
> Independent candidates who did \emph{not} run in the last

< {\em Democracy may be simply defined as the people in action.}                  
---
> \emph{Democracy may be simply defined as the people in action.}

Note that with \emph{} you do not need to add the italic correction space with \/.

Use a single \vspace{1in} command instead of multiple \blns
 < \bln \bln \bln                                                                  
 ---
 > \vspace{1in}


Get rid of the underlining, TeX is not a typewriter!  And since you only have a single line of text I prefer to use \centerline{}, but that is just a personal preference.
 < \begin{center}                                                                  
 < \underline{Afterword: Independent Candidates}                                   
 < \end{center}                                                                    
 ---                                                                                 
 > \centerline{\textbf{Afterword: Independent Candidates}}




I'd emphasize that usage of \be and \ee is discouraged and change \vskip 1in into the proper \vspace{1in}. Good you removed the pesky underlining.

+1. Nice touch to replace the instances of {\em ...} with \emph{..., letting you get rid of the manual italic corrections. I would als change Wm. Mott Stewart to Wm.\ Mott Stewart in the \author direcdtive, to avoid getting unnecessary whitespace after Wm..

That is really great, thanks so much.  Rescued a document from long ago.  I am passing on various stuff to my kinds, and it is really nice to be able to include this.  A small thing, tried to do my part, had some effect on legislation that provided public funding along these lines for several years, until a new government replaced it, hopefully it will come back.  Thanks all.

\title, \date and \author can still be used after \begin{document} and some people prefer it (e.g. to be able to use babel shorthands without explicitly enabling them). So IMHO item 2 is optional.
